# GitHub search multiple organizations

Tags: github

I'm using the GitHub search features described here:
https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories

I usually search for something like this:

```
involves:Kim org:orgA is:open
```

But I also want to search like this:

```
involves:Kim org:orgA or orgB is:open
```

which means searching for all `open` issues throughout `orgA` and `orgB` that involve user `Kim`, but my query didn't work. Is it possible to search like that?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for searching across multiple orgs is only supported for code searches. You can test this by searching across multiple orgs:

`(org:orgA OR org:orgB)`

This will only return results in the code filter.